# Facebook App featuring secret friend's name?

Tags: facebook, facebook-friends

Is it possible to create a facebook app without totally showing who used the app?

For example, I'd like to post a wall message to one of my friends. But when the message appears on my friend's wall, my real name would not appear. In other words, my friends knows the person who posted the message is one of his friends, but not which friend.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is not possible. Posting to anyone's wall will always show the sender's Username. This was previously possible via [Notifications](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-notifications/), allowing you to send a notification to the friend to say 'a secret person has sent you a message' etc. But the new API now only lets you send notifications to users of your application only.